# error in converting string from editText in android

Tags: android

i try to make converter from string to binary in android

**this is my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Converter converter;
    static EditText str;
    TextView hasil;
    Button convert;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    str = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_string);
    hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_hasil);

    final String kata =str.toString();
    convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_conv);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            converter = new Converter();
            converter.aksi1();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**and this is my Converter class**

```
public class Converter extends MainActivity {
    EditText str;
    TextView hasil;
    String kata = str.getText().toString();
    public void aksi1(){
            if (kata != null){

            byte[] bytes = kata.getBytes();
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for(byte b : bytes){
                int val = b;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);// i dont know what this mean
                    val <<= 1;
                }
            }
            hasil.setText(binary);
        }
        else{
            convert.setEnabled(false);
        }


}
```

}

**and this the error i get when i run that code**

```
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.example.strtobin.Converter.<init>(Converter.java:11)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.example.strtobin.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 15:17:39.798: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what happen with line 11? and please tell me what this code mean 
**binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1)**

very big thanks for your help... :)

Comment: I would recommend actually learning Java and Android rather than trying to build apps with copy/paste.  Copy/paste programming does need give good results and what will you do when you release it and the bugs start appearing?

Comment: hmm..., in about 3 month..., can i understanding them? and have you a tutorial java and android which is easy to understanding..., if you have.., can i request to have it?? thanks...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes in Converter class
  1: "str" and "hasil" are hiding the instance of super class variables
  2: they were not initialized
In MainActivity
  1: "hasil" is not static

Here is the working code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
Converter converter;
static EditText str;
static TextView hasil;
Button convert;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    str = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_string);
    hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_hasil);
    convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_conv);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            converter = new Converter();
            converter.aksi1();
        }
    });
}
public class Converter extends MainActivity {
    String kata;
    public void aksi1(){
            kata = str.getText().toString();

            if (kata != null){

            byte[] bytes = kata.getBytes();
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for(byte b : bytes){
                int val = b;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);// i dont know what this mean
                    val <<= 1;
                }
            }
            hasil.setText(""+binary.toString());
        }
        else{
            convert.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: very big thanks..., thats worked..., actually i must learn more about inherritance, thanks @JD.com

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see with the code is that the `TextView hasil` is never assigned an object.  The `hasil` object is then used later in the code.

```
public class Converter extends MainActivity {
    EditText str;

    TextView hasil;  //Never assigned so hasil == null

    String kata = str.getText().toString();
    public void aksi1(){
            if (kata != null){

            byte[] bytes = kata.getBytes();
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for(byte b : bytes){
                int val = b;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);// i dont know what this mean
                    val <<= 1;
                }
            }

            hasil.setText(binary); //Here hasil is being used but is null

        }
        else{
            convert.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: i mean i just want to initialize that hasil is textview,and that textview is used to print the result of the converter. is that must be assigned a value?

Comment: @adhit_yogapratama Exactly, if hasil is null calling a method on it such as `setText` is going to throw a NPE (Null Pointer Exception)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized any field in your converter instance, for that purpose create a parameterized constructor and use it to create an instance of your converter such as:

```
public class Converter{
    EditText str;
    TextView hasil;

public Converter(EditText str, TextView hasil){
this.str = str;
this.hasil = hasil;
}
// DO OTHER STUFF...
}
```